# MS SQL Server: advanced substring, splitting one string column to multimle columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a column in a table, I would like to separate the contents into different columns, locations of dash is not always same. Please advise more simple code.

Thanks.

```
       COL1
AGH-WH6X-23-4534-OPDQE-QADF  
xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx    
xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xx 
x-xx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx    
xxx-xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-x 
xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xx    
x-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xx 
xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xx
```

Expectation:

```
COL2  COL3  COL4  COL5  COL6   COL7
AGH   WH6X  23    4534  OPDQE  QADF
xxx   xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxx    NULL
```

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data *and* desired results would be helpful.  If you want to split a string in SQL Server, you might want to Google "sql server split".

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i have a working query, just would like to know if its can be done with more simple query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a recursive CTE with aggregation:

```
with cte as (
      select col1, left(col1, charindex('-', col1 + '-') - 1) as val,
             1 as level,
             substring(col1, charindex('-', col1) + 1, len(col1)) as rest
      from t
      union all
      select col1, left(rest, charindex('-', rest + '-') - 1),
             level + 1,
             substring(rest, charindex('-', rest + '-') + 1, len(col1))
      from cte
      where rest > ''
     )
select max(case when level = 1 then val end) as val1,
       max(case when level = 2 then val end) as val2,
       max(case when level = 3 then val end) as val3,
       max(case when level = 4 then val end) as val4,
       max(case when level = 5 then val end) as val5,
       max(case when level = 6 then val end) as val6,
       max(case when level = 7 then val end) as val7
from cte
group by col1;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this query taking too much time to run for large scale table. Is there any way to optimize it, Thanks.

Comment: @JavlonIsmatov . . . You might want to ask another question, with sample data, desired results and referencing this question.  The idea is:  "this code works, but I want to make it faster".